# Service class null pointer

Tags: java, android

I have created a service class for my network connection so that my app can create a connection and then access the input and output streams throughout the program. I have instantiated the service class in the first activity but whenever I try and access a get method from the service class i get a null pointer exception. The weird thing is, when i debug the program it does not get this error.

Here is the class that is getting the code:

```
public class WaitingActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{
WaitingNetwork roleGetter;
String role;
int gotrole = 0;
Intent intent;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.waitingroom);   


    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WaitingActivity.this, "", 
            "Loading. Please wait...", true);
}
Networking mService;
boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Networking.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

/** Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches to
 * this method with the android:onClick attribute) */


/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};


ObjectInputStream stream;
public void getStream(){
    stream = mService.getStateOis();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    getStream();

    roleGetter = new WaitingNetwork(stream);
    Thread fred = new Thread(roleGetter);
    fred.start();
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
03-26 15:41:16.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
03-26 15:41:16.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 15:41:16.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at  com.DrawTastic.WaitingActivity.getStream(WaitingActivity.java:82)
03-26 15:41:16.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.DrawTastic.WaitingActivity.run(WaitingActivity.java:88)
03-26 15:41:16.374: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301): Activity com.DrawTastic.WaitingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405320a0 that was originally added here
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.DrawTastic.WaitingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405320a0 that was originally added here
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at com.DrawTastic.WaitingActivity.onCreate(WaitingActivity.java:33)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-26 15:41:18.454: E/WindowManager(1301):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Without an exception stacktrace, there's not much we can do for you.

Comment: on the mService.getStateOis();

Comment: Sounds like a race condition.  You need to show us more code to help you, but I would guess that when you are not debugging, you call `getStateOis()` before the service is bound.  When you are debugging, then your service is bound before you make the call to `getStateOis()`.

Comment: Post some code from your getStateOis() method in the Networking class. Think your problem lies here. Nullpointers are probably the easiers error to find, since it tells you that you are trying to call something that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a race condition.  You start a thread in `onCreate(Bundle)`, and that thread is expecting `mService` to refer to an instance of some sort, but that instance isn't populated until your `Service` is bound (which happens in `onStart()`).

I am not sure, but can your Service be bound in `onCreate(Bundle)` (specifically, before you start your `Thread`), or can your thread be started in `onStart()` (specifically, after your `Service` is bound)?  Doing either one of those can help, but your best bet would be to use some sort of listener pattern, which utilizes callbacks (much as the android application framework does).

Comment: Minor correction: it's not populated until onServiceConnected(), because bindService() is asynchronous and does not block whilst the service is created. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Binding) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Your Thread starts in onCreate() and your servise binds in onStart() (after onCreate), so mService is null

Answer (score 0):

It is a race condition, as Nicholas points out.

By calling bindService(), you haven't positively done anything - you've just requested that the service start. It's only when onServiceConnected() is called that the service is ready.

Add a listener pattern to your service. Have existing listeners fired during onServiceConnected(), and once that's happened, fire any new listeners immediately. Then don't make any service calls until your usage class has received that callback to say that the service is ready.